# update statement fails and no error is produced

Tags: php, mysql

```
   if(isset($_POST['admin_email']))
   {
      $conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","","");
  mysql_select_db("qasite" ,$conn) or die(mysql_error());


 $email=mysql_escape_string($_POST['admin_email']);

   mysql_query(" UPDATE admin_details 
                 SET email='$email'
                 WHERE admin_id=1
            ") or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

   echo 'Update was successful';
}
```

The update statment at the end appears, but no record appears in the database. By default I set the admin_id equal 1, and no update happens. Why is that?

Comment: @Dmitri does your table "admin_details" contain any data

Comment: is there a record to start with?

Comment: well, one field is set as a default of 1..and the other record is empty. I updated 2 default values. it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but no record appears in the database.

You can use `UPDATE` only on records that exist. If there is no record WHERE admin_id = 1, the query won't update non-existing rows.

You could use `INSERT` and work with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. (then email should be an UNIQUE index).

Answer (score 0):

You can change `trigger_error` to `die(mysql_error())` and see if it works better.

Comment: $conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","",""); to $conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","")?

Comment: have you checked the php log file?